# Connection string failing

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I am having an issue with login failing with this connection string:

`<add name="WorkflowConfiguration" connectionString="Server=JRITCHIE-VM\GETSMART;  Database=WorkFlow Creation; uid= JRITCHIE-VM\sa1; password= ****;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>`

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, please edit your question to tag it with the correct relational database product (mysql, ms-sql-server, or whatever) since this seriously affects resolution of this problem. You also need to provide the exact error message you are getting, please. Does the connection work ok from the appropriate IDE (MySQL Workbench, SQL Server Management Studio, or whatever)?

Comment: The error is saying the login failed. I think I may have fixed the issue.

Comment: That's good, but there must be a database connection error message somewhere, all databases will tell you more about what's wrong than just 'login failed'.

Comment: I forgot to add a tag. This is for C# with Visual Studio and that is all I got.

Comment: When you experience an error and you ask a question about that error **you need to include that error in your question.** Alternatively try to figure it out for your self first, copy the beginning of the error message text into your fav. search engine (or [so]) and see what other's have tried to fix it.

Comment: Error `Login failed` there you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution, was that I needed to adjust my VM network setting because it was creating its own IP off my computer. So we adjusted the settings so it would connect directly to the network. This allowed the SQL server to show up when trying to create a connection.

I then had to turn on mixed mode authentication, so it would take a SQL login. This solved the issue.

Thanks!